# Using package desolve - can the states be defined by a matrix?

Tags: r, ode

I'm trying to make a model using deSolve with a fairly large number of states. One of the states, 'foo', is actually made of 15 different states comprising of foo[1,1:5], foo[2,1:5] and foo[3,1:5] so I thought it would be easiest to pass the function a matrix of states instead of typing them out individually and then I could refer to them with indexing:

```
  par <- rep(NA,3)
  par_names <- c('alpha','prog','death_rate')
  names(par) <-par_names
  par['alpha'] <- 0.7
  par['prog'] <- 0.8
  par['death_rate'] <- 0.3

  foo <- matrix(0,nrow = 3,ncol = 5)

  states <- foo

  my_func <- function(t,states,par){
    with(as.list(c(states,par)),{

      for (j in 1:5){
        dfoo[1,j] <-  par['alpha']*par['prog']*foo[1,j] - par['death_rate']*foo[1,j]
        dfoo[2,j] <- par['prog']*foo[1,j] - par['prog']*foo[2,j] - par['death_rate']*foo[2,j]
        dfoo[3,j] <- par['prog']*foo[2,j] - par['prog']*foo[3,j] - par['death_rate']*foo[3,j]
      }


      list(c(
        dfoo[]
      ))
    })
  }

  times <- seq(1,365,by=1)

  library(deSolve)

  alldata <- as.data.frame(ode(y=states,times=times,func=my_func,parms=par))
```

I've tried to fix it but I just keep getting the same error:

```
 Error in dfoo[1, j] <- par["alpha"] * par["prog"] * foo[1, j] - par["death_rate"] *  : 
  object 'dfoo' not found
```

So does anyone know how this might be made to work or an easier way of doing this?

Comment: The error message says it all. The `[<-` function does not create an object if one does not exist, no matter how much you want it to.

Comment: Ok fair enough, it's an obvious error now that you've pointed it out.

Comment: Well,,,, I thought it was obvious as soon as the error message was printed.

Comment: I'm new to this. The main question though - can it even be done? Can a state be given to the function as a matrix? I can't find anything on the internet to say it can or can't, but maybe I'm not reading the right things...

Comment: Ah sorry, that wasn't my intention at all! If I understand your comment correctly, the function I'm using is given in the last line - ode(). Is that what you meant?

Comment: It was. Didn't recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a matrix in as your states. But every time `ode` calls your function (except for the first time) it will pass a `vector` rather than a `matrix`. But you can convert it to a matrix at the beginning of your function.

You use unnecessary contortions to create your data. Also, as pointed out in the comments, your function doesn't seem to initialize `dfoo`. Finally, your `for` loop in the function could be more cleanly handled with a few vectorized operations. Here is an example:

```
my_func <- function(t,states,par){
    foo <- matrix(states, nrow = 3, ncol = 5)
    dfoo <- with(as.list(par), rbind(    
      (prog * alpha * foo[1,]) - (death_rate * foo[1,]),
      (prog * foo[-nrow(foo),]) - (prog * foo[-1,]) - (death_rate * foo[-1,])
    ))
    list(dfoo)
}

library(deSolve)
par <- c(alpha = 0.7, prog = 0.8, death_rate = 0.3)
states <- matrix(0,nrow = 3,ncol = 5)
ode <- ode(y=states, times=1:365, func=my_func, parms=par)
alldata <- as.data.frame(ode)
```